# Simulate Tab Key Pressed on Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

It is possible to Simulate a Tab Key when another key is pressed? I'm looking to do exactly the same, but with the `DOWN & ENTER Key.`

I know about the `onKeyDown` function. I'm trying this but it doesn't work.

```
private function onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ) :void
            {
                if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN )
                {
                    (e.currentTarget as TextInput).dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, true, false, 0, Keyboard.TAB));
                }
            }
```

I know tab works differently, I saw it in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333543/flex-simulate-key-press) but still not idea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried it on the keyup event. Keydown fires first, and then keyup last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it like this. Hope this helps somebody else later.

```
private function onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ) :void
            {
                if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN || e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
                {                   
                    focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent().setFocus();

                }
                if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
                {
                    focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent(true).setFocus();
                }
            }
```

In Flash, focusManager by itself may be undefined in that context. Change to:
evt.currentTarget.focusManager.getNextFocusManagerComponent().setFocus();

Answer (score -1):

Try to put tabbing component in array, then change focus manually with:

```
stage.focus = myComp;
```

or

```
stage.focus = myComps[currentCompOrderNumber+1];
```