# ActionScript simulate keyboard press

Tags: events, actionscript, keyboard, simulate

i am trying to simulate the pressing of the TAB key. I have search for quite a while and found no answer to that.

I tried:

```
dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, true, false, Keyboard.TAB, 0, 0, false, false, false);
```

but nothing happens..

any hints on what i am doing wrong? How can i simulate the keyboard press?

Comment: Why do you want to simulate `[TAB]` key press? What's the desired behaviour?

Comment: i am working on a flash player project. There are some options you can add by opening some "windows". but when you close the windows the keyboard shortcuts dont work anymore. But if you press tab the keyboard shortcuts are activated again. so now i want to make it simulate a [TAB] before every keystroke action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can't completely recreate a key being pressed since that is all user input and not programmatic. However, a program reacts (mostly) to user input through events. By invoking an event through dispatchEvent you are (mostly) recreating what would happen if that event originated through user input.

[source](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?271862-Simulate-Key-Press).

What are you trying to achieve? 
Switching focus on UI-Elements? [Then check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026720/simulate-tab-key-pressed-on-flex).

Inserting tab space? [Then check this out](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flash-Flex-ActionScript/String/InsertingSpecialWhitespaceCharactersTabt.htm).

Comment: i am working on a flash player project. There are some options you can add by opening some "windows". but when you close the windows the keyboard shortcuts dont work anymore. But if you press tab the keyboard shortcuts are activated again. so now i want to make it simulate a [TAB] before every keystroke action. I will try the solution on the link tou sent me. thanks!

Comment: Are you opening real windows or "fake" ones? Real windows steal the focus and it might happen that focus won't be returned to the "parent" window. It might as well be a event-specific problem but I have to admit that my AS knowledge is a bit rusty.

Have you looked into your event listeners to see wether any of them is actually fired, if not, that might be a good route to take when debuging.

Comment: it's a fake window.. the focus is still on the flash player after the window closes.. I am now considering putting the focus always on the same item.. I will also check the event listener. thanks for your help!